# How to delete references to mapped drivers?

Tags: windows

If I open FileManager on the right side I see a few drivers

```
>C
>D
>K
>L
>N
>Y
>Z
```

Here drivers C and D is PC dirvers, but others K, L, N, Y, Z are mapped drivers that I don't need to see at my file manager.

So, question is - how to remove these refs on external drivers from my file manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open cmd.exe  and then run:

Net Use  Z: /Delete

Do this for all mapped drives.

Now restart and the mapped drives will be gone.